# Splitting complex string between symbols R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a dataset full of IDs and qualification strings. My issue with this is two fold;
How to deal with splits between different symbols and,
how to iterate output down a dataframe whilst retaining an ID.

```
ID <- c(1,2,3)
Qualstring <- c("LE:Science = 45 Distinctions",
              "A:Chemistry = A A:Biology = A A:Mathematics = A",
              "A:Biology = A A:Chemistry = A A:Mathematics = A B:Baccalaureate Advanced Diploma = Pass"
              )

s <- data.frame(ID, Qualstring)
```

The desired output would be:

```
      ID Qualification Subject                              Grade
1     1 LE:            Science                              45 Distinctions   
2     2 A:             Chemistry                            A    
3     2 A:             Biology                              A    
4     2 A:             Mathematics                          A    
5     3 A:             Biology                              A    
6     3 A:             Chemistry                            A    
7     3 A:             Mathematics                          A    
8     3 WB:            Welsh Baccalaureate Advanced Diploma Pass
```

The commonality of the splits is the ":" and "=", and the codes/words around those.

Looking at the problem from my perspective, it appears complex and whether a continued fudge in excel is ultimately the way to go for this structure of data. Would love to know otherwise if there are any recommendations or direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `data.table` and `stringr`. The use of `data.table` is just for my personal convenience, you could use `data.frame` with `do.call(rbind,.)` instead of `rbindlist()`

```
library(stringr)
qual <- str_extract_all(s$Qualstring,"[A-Z]+(?=\\:)")
subject <- str_extract_all(s$Qualstring,"(?<=\\:)[\\w ]+")
grade <- str_extract_all(s$Qualstring,"(?<=\\= )[A-z0-9]+")

library(data.table)
df <- lapply(seq(s$ID),function(i){
  N = length(qual[[i]])
  data.table(ID = rep(s[i,"ID"],N),
             Qualification = qual[[i]],
             Subject = subject[[i]],
             Grade = grade[[i]]
             )
}) %>% rbindlist()


   ID Qualification                         Subject Grade
1:  1            LE                        Science     45
2:  2             A                      Chemistry      A
3:  2             A                        Biology      A
4:  2             A                    Mathematics      A
5:  3             A                        Biology      A
6:  3             A                      Chemistry      A
7:  3             A                    Mathematics      A
8:  3             B Baccalaureate Advanced Diploma   Pass
```

In short, I use  positive look behind `(?<=)` and positive look ahead `(?=)`. `[A-Z]+` is for a group of upper letters, `[\\w ]+` for a group of words and spaces, `[A-z0-9]+` for letters (up and low cases) and numbers. `string_extract_all` gives a list with all the match on each cell of the character vector tested.

Comment: Wow that was quick, thank you so much - I'll go through this to try and understand, regex is a whole new world for me.

Comment: Happy to help. I tried to give a bit of help concerning regex. There is plenty of help about it, and I recommand strongly the use of `stringr`, in addition to the basic functions `gsub`, `grep` and so on.

Comment: For next time, try to give your attempts with your question. Some people voted to close your question because you are asking for the entire solution

Comment: I wanted to ask - is there a reason for you using [A-z0-9] or [A-Z] in lieu of [:alnum:] or [:upper:]? Again thank you, your working example has really helped me get to grips with the fundamental syntax of regex and use in StringR.

Comment: No, just bad habbits. Actually ` [:alnum:]` is even better, because `[A-z]` includes some non letters